# aws: EMR cluster fails "ERROR UserData: Error encountered while try to get user data" on submitting spark job

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr

Successfully started aws EMR cluster, but any submission fails with:

```
19/07/30 08:37:42 ERROR UserData: Error encountered while try to get user data
java.io.IOException: File '/var/aws/emr/userData.json' cannot be read
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.openInputStream(FileUtils.java:296)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(FileUtils.java:1711)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(FileUtils.java:1748)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.util.UserData.getUserData(UserData.java:62)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.util.UserData.<init>(UserData.java:39)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.util.UserData.ofDefaultResourceLocations(UserData.java:52)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.util.AWSSessionCredentialsProviderFactory.buildSTSClient(AWSSessionCredentialsProviderFactory.java:52)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.util.AWSSessionCredentialsProviderFactory.<clinit>(AWSSessionCredentialsProviderFactory.java:17)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.rolemapping.DefaultS3CredentialsResolver.resolve(DefaultS3CredentialsResolver.java:22)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.guice.CredentialsProviderOverrider.override(CredentialsProviderOverrider.java:25)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.executor.GlobalS3Executor.executeOverriders(GlobalS3Executor.java:130)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.executor.GlobalS3Executor.execute(GlobalS3Executor.java:86)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.invoke(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:184)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.doesBucketExist(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:90)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.ensureBucketExists(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:139)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.initialize(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:116)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.initialize(S3NativeFileSystem.java:508)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.initialize(EmrFileSystem.java:111)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2859)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:99)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2896)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:392)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.org$apache$spark$deploy$DependencyUtils$$resolveGlobPath(DependencyUtils.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$$anonfun$resolveGlobPaths$2.apply(DependencyUtils.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$$anonfun$resolveGlobPaths$2.apply(DependencyUtils.scala:144)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:35)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.resolveGlobPaths(DependencyUtils.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$3.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:354)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$3.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:354)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:354)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

**userData.json** isn't part of my application, looks like it is emr internals.

Any ideas what is wrong? I submit jobs via livy requests.
Cluster setup:
2 core nodes m4.large
7 task nodes m5.4xlarge
1 master node m5.xlarge

Comment: possible [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25708240/amazon-emr-and-hive-getting-a-java-io-ioexception-not-a-file-exception-when)

Comment: I don't think this is related unless this is something Amazon did incorrectly. The directory in this SO is internal to EMR and not a target directory for a spark job.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct way to fix this is by running the following command as part of your bootstrap script when launching EMR (or, if running on a Glue Endpoint, run the following at any point on your endpoint):

```
chmod 444 /var/aws/emr/userData.json
```

Comment: okay, I ssh'ed into my glue EMR developer endpoint with root user, and tried running this command, but it says Operation not permitted. Then tried with sudo, but I don't know the password of root. Any idea on from where can I get that ?

Comment: correct, the root cause is by default permission for `/var/aws/emr/userData.json` is 440, `-r--r--r-- 1 hadoop hadoop /var/aws/emr/userData.json`, if running with other user then there is permission issue.

Comment: @AnumSheraz - have you used bootstrap scripts?  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html

Comment: Do you know how to run this command in a scala script? @EricMeadows

Comment: @Doe - from what I know, I do not believe that it can be done at runtime because of the way the operation is kicked off.  Bootstrap scripts would be best :).

Comment: I also run into the same issues when running glue jobs. But, all glue jobs finish successfully. I am really curious if this is something we should worry about.

Comment: @Raymond - it's not an issue - it's just annoying to see in the logs.

Answer (score 1):

I've face the similar issue in AWS EMR emr-5.24.1(spark 2.4.1), but jobs are never failed.

Comment: I actually realised it doesn't fail the job, but still have no idea what is about

Comment: Spark 2.4.3 on AWS Glue Dev Endpoint - also shows same error.. Annoying..