# AWS Glue Endpoint - error File '/var/aws/emr/userData.json' cannot be read

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue

I am connecting to AWS Glue Endpoint and when trying to run jobs - getting error:
`File '/var/aws/emr/userData.json' cannot be read`

I can not access any file in EMR cluster to chmod or other things.. How to fix this error trough PySpark console?

Thanks.

Comment: '/var/aws/emr/userData.json', this path will not exist on the glue's local filesystem or HDFS. Could you share your code snippet to get more clarity on the issue.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57268057/aws-emr-cluster-fails-error-userdata-error-encountered-while-try-to-get-user