# AWS Glue - Dev Endpoint - 'userData.json' error

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue

Every time new Dev Endpoint is created (new cluster) - this error show up at first:

```
] util.UserData (UserData.java:getUserData(70)) - Error encountered while try to get user data
java.io.IOException: File '/var/aws/emr/userData.json' cannot be read
```

How to resolve it?

Thannks.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57268057/aws-emr-cluster-fails-error-userdata-error-encountered-while-try-to-get-user

Comment: Not duplicate. Same error but different environment. I can NOT change mode of that file because there is no access to that file..

Comment: Then we both are on same boat. https://stackoverflow.com/q/60839451/5167801

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the known issue when working with EMR clusters or Glue Dev Endpoints.
When working with the EMR cluster you can always give the permission to the file and the error will just fade away.

`chmod 777 /var/aws/emr/userData.json`

But when using glue Dev Endpoint we are not provided with the root access.
The AWS support suggests to **ignore the error and continue the execution as it doesn't stops the execution**.

So I tried running my script and it generates the output despite throwing the error.

Hope it helps.